# "Displaying X to Y of Z results" using Codeigniter pagination library?

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I am, using the Codeigniter pagination library,

I am wondering how I can grab the number of the first and last items displayed using the pagination class?

So, if I had 12 results, and per_page was set to 5. I would want

Page 1: `Displaying 1 to 5 of 12 results`
Page 2: `Displaying 6 to 10 of 12 results`
Page 3: `Displaying 11 to 12 of 12 results`.

Comment: Maybe not an answer but could be an alternative: https://github.com/qeremy/codeigniterpager

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Keeping it simple.

You need 3 variables. Result start, result end (in the page, not the whole) and total result.

1. You already know the total results (from the pagination). Let's call it `$total`.
2. so, now get the current page (`$curpage`) value from CI instance. Then,

   ```
   $result_start = ($curpage - 1) * $per_page + 1;
   if ($result_start == 0) $result_start= 1; // *it happens only for the first run*
   ```
3. for `$result_end`, you just need to add the per page value but considering it'll be 1 less,

   ```
   $result_end = $result_start+$per_page-1;

   if ($result_end < $per_page)   // happens when records less than per page  
       $result_end = $per_page;  
   else if ($result_end > $total)  // happens when result end is greater than total records  
       $result_end = $total;
   ```
4. send all those 3 values to view.

   ```
   echo "displaying $result_start to $result_end of $total";
   ```

Comment: here i will add in $result_start <=0, becouse some times $curpage doesn´t give me a value, and then the result is -2, for example

Answer (score 3):

itachi's solution works great except you need to handle the case where the last page has less than $per_page elements.

```
if ($result_end > $total) {
    $result_end = $total;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps this would be better as a comment on itachi's solution.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to comment on others solutions yet :)

Answer (score 0):

In CodeIgniter Controller file

```
$params['limit'] = 15;
        $params['offset'] = ($this->input->get('per_page')) ? $this->input->get('per_page') : 0;
        $config = $this->config->item('pagination');
        $config['per_page'] = $params['limit'];
        $config['base_url'] = site_url('cy_controller/action?');
        $config['total_rows'] = $this->abcd_model->get_count($params);
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        $data['merchant'] = $this->abcd_model->get_all($params);
        $countMerchant = count($data['merchant']);
        if ($params['offset'] == 0) {
            $find_total_record = $countMerchant;
        } else {
            $valuec = $params['offset'] + $params['limit'];
            if ($valuec > $config['total_rows'])
                $find_total_record = $params['offset'] + $countMerchant;
            else
                $find_total_record = $params['offset'] + $params['limit'];
        }
        $per_page_total = $find_total_record;

        $initial = $params['offset'] == 0 ? 1 : $params['offset'];
        $data['showing'] = "Showing  " . $initial . " to " . $per_page_total . " of " . $config['total_rows'] . " results";
        $data['_view'] = 'cy_controller/action';
        $this->load->view('layouts/main', $data);
```

And in view file

```
 <div class="pull-left">
     <?php echo $showing; ?>
  </div>
```