# how to show pagination information using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i want to show pagination information in my page. 
 like this  ***Below table is showing 0-8 books out of 17 books***

As explained below in comments and answer i tried to fix my problem. But still i have problem.

1. Unable to get the `cur_page` value. I tried
                       `$CI =& get_instance(); 
                        $curpage=$CI->pagination->cur_page;`  But this is giving me a
   zero value.
2. if i supply manual value for `cur_page` . say $cur_page=3, and my total record is 17. Then at the last page(i.e 3) it is showing wrong information  `showing 24-17 of 17 books`

Please help me to fix this problem?

In my view page

```
 <?php    echo "displaying $result_start to $result_end of $total";?>
```

In controller

```
 $config = array();  
    $config['base_url'] = base_url().'viewallbooks/books/pgn/';
    $config["total_rows"] = $this->Booksmodel->record_count_for_secondtopBooks('3');
    $config['uri_segment'] = 4;
    $config['per_page'] = 8;
    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<div id="pagination">';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</div>'; 

       $this->pagination->initialize($config);
       $page = ($this->uri->segment(4)) ? $this->uri->segment(4) : 0;

    $data["query"] = $this->Subjectmodel->get_subjects();
    $data["query1"]=  $this->Editionmodel->get_edition();

    /*
     * For showing the "showing 8-16 of 23 data
     */
    $data["flimit"]=$config["per_page"];
    $data["slimit"]=$page;
    $data["trows"]= $config["total_rows"] ; 
     /*
     * Ends here--For showing the "showing 8-16 of 23 data
     */

    $data["query2"]=$this->Booksmodel->get_all_book_list_atHomeTop('3',$config["per_page"], $page);
     $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
    $this->load->view('commonfiles/booksview',$data);
```

In Model for counting total number of rows

```
  //-- -Counting the rows of bookdetails of table where display_id is as  argument----- 
 public function record_count_for_secondtopBooks($id) {
    $this->load->database(); 
     $this->db->where('display_id', $id);
     $this->db->from('bookdetails');
    return $this->db->count_all_results();
}
```

Comment: refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14533206/displaying-x-to-y-of-z-results-using-codeigniter-pagination-library/14533776#14533776

Comment: @itachi in this link you have mention `so, now get the current page value from CI instance`  .But i don't know how to get the  current page value?

Comment: `$CI=& get_instance()`. Then just var dump the instance and see where  the current page is located. then get it accordingly. Its been a while since i used CI so can't remember exactly. should be under pagination object.

Comment: @itachi this is my first project in php. so really its difficult to understand your comment. can you share  code for getting current page value?

Comment: you are taking it way more complicatedly than it is. It is just 2 lines of code. 1st line `$CI =& get_instance()`. 2nd line, `var_dump($CI)`. There you will see the current page in one of the key value pairs in paginator object. Then get it via getter. (e.g. `$CI->paginator->cur_page`)

Comment: Where is your model? That is likely where the error is.

Comment: @RickCalder as itachi refer me a example, there he have mentioned `so, now get the current page value from CI instance.' But i don't know how to get the current page value?

Comment: @itachi i updated my code as you explained. But still i am unable to fix my issue. please check my update

Comment: @RickCalder i updated my question above please go through it once again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var_dump($this->pagination);` returns somenthing like this:

```
object(CI_Pagination)
21 (31) { 
    ["base_url"]=> string(31) "http://localhost/site/users" 
    ["prefix"]=> string(0) "" 
    ["suffix"]=> string(0) "" 
    ["total_rows"]=> int(3) 
    ["per_page"]=> int(20) 
    ["num_links"]=> int(15) 
    ["cur_page"]=> int(0) 
    ["first_link"]=> string(5) "First" 
    ["next_link"]=> bool(false) 
    ["prev_link"]=> bool(false) 
    ["last_link"]=> string(4) "Last" 
    ["uri_segment"]=> int(2) 
    ["full_tag_open"]=> string(25) "" 
    ["full_tag_close"]=> string(4) "" 
    ["first_tag_open"]=> string(31) "" 
    ["first_tag_close"]=> string(13) " " 
    ["last_tag_open"]=> string(36) " " 
    ["last_tag_close"]=> string(7) "" 
    ["first_url"]=> string(31) "http://localhost/site/users" 
    ["cur_tag_open"]=> string(87) " " 
    ["cur_tag_close"]=> string(11) "" 
    ["next_tag_open"]=> string(36) " " 
    ["next_tag_close"]=> string(13) " " 
    ["prev_tag_open"]=> string(36) " " 
    ["prev_tag_close"]=> string(7) "" 
    ["num_tag_open"]=> string(35) " " 
    ["num_tag_close"]=> string(7) "" 
    ["page_query_string"]=> bool(false) 
    ["query_string_segment"]=> string(8) "per_page" 
    ["display_pages"]=> bool(true) 
    ["anchor_class"]=> string(26) "class="button bradiusMax" " }
```

i should do:

```
echo "Showing ".( $this->pagination->cur_page * $this->pagination->per_page)." of ". $this->pagination->total_rows." total results";
```

if you want you can use also different formats as itachi showed you in comments.

Comment: but i am looking for this format `showing 0-8 books  of 82 books`

Comment: i applied your code. but at the last page it is showing wrong infomation. Say i have 17 books, at both page it is showing correct data but at last it is showing wrong.  It should show `Showing 17 of 17 total results` but it is showing `Showing 24 of 17 total results`  What could be the reason?

Comment: you need to use some logic.... let's say `$param = $this->pagination->cur_page * $this->pagination->per_page`. now if `$param > $this->pagination->total_rows`, then just make the `$param = $this->pagination->total_rows`.... job done.... Now think how to do it.

Comment: But i'l mention, there is a flaw in your approach. The last page will say showing 17 of 17 books which means, all records should be there. But in practice it'l show only one book. The 17th one. Which can be best say as 17-17 of 17 books which says it is the last book. Think along this line.

Answer (score 3):

I used this Code for generating pagination information

```
if($config["total_rows"]>10){
    if($this->pagination->cur_page==1)
        $start = $this->pagination->cur_page;
    else
        $start = (($this->pagination->cur_page-1) * $this->pagination->per_page)+1;

    if($this->pagination->cur_page * $this->pagination->per_page > $config["total_rows"])
        $end = $config["total_rows"];
    else
        $end = $this->pagination->cur_page * $this->pagination->per_page;

    $data['pagination_des'] = "Showing ".($start)." to ".($end)." from ". $config["total_rows"]." results";
}else
{
    $data['pagination_des'] = "Showing ".($this->pagination->cur_page+1)." to ".($config["total_rows"])." from ". $config["total_rows"]." results";
}
```