# Showing 1 to 20 of 250 entries codeigniter pagination

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I want to show this type of thing in my page when returning data from table

showing 1 to 20 from 250 entries  //when in first page

showing 21 to 40 from 250 entries //when in second page

showing 41 to 60 from 250 entries //when in third page

i have tried but not get it 
also i have seen this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14533206/displaying-x-to-y-of-z-results-using-codeigniter-pagination-library)

but dont understand where to put this code and how to do this

Comment: what is your query to retrieve data from table, your view page and controller function. At least what have you tried that is not working as your expectation.

Comment: I solved it vai now... thanks

Comment: You can check [Pagination class](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/pagination.html).

Answer (score 0):

Somehow i got my answer...but i am not sure is it a good solution or not..I put it here..you guyz are welcome to criticize..thanks

```
<?php
                        $curpage=$this->uri->segment(3); 
                        if($curpage<$per_page){
                            $result_start=1; 
                            $result_end=$curpage+$per_page;
                        }
                        else {
                            $result_start=$curpage+1;
                            $result_end=$curpage+$per_page;
                            if($result_end>$total){$result_end=$total;}
                        }

                        echo "Displaying $result_start to $result_end of $total";
                        ?>
```